# Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, jsonparser, react-google-login

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)  
vendors~main.chunk.js:32926 The above error occurred in the <Home> component:

    at Home (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1640:99)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:131876:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:132298:5)
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:132236:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:130557:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ vendors~main.chunk.js:32926
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Home (main.chunk.js:1643:72)
  
VM23:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
  


**CODE**
```

const Home = () => {
const scrollRef = useRef(null);
const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : localStorage.clear();
useEffect(() => {
const query = userQuery(userInfo?.sub);

```
     client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
       setUser(data[0]);
   })
   }, []);


   useEffect(()=>{
       scrollRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
    
     },[])
```

Comment: please edit your question to make it more readable

Comment: Can you post what you are getting if you console.log of `localStorage.getItem('user')`

Answer (score 3):

while you are storing the data in the local storage use `JSON.stringify(data)` instead of directly storing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are getting string `"[object Object]"` from the `localStorage.getItem('user')` which basically is useless. Keep in mind localstorage act as dictionary but ONLY stores strings not objects. As @Naman Agrawal pointed out, convert your data to string before storing it into localstorage

```js
localstorage['user'] = JSON.stringify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For more accurate localization of the error, more info is needed.
If we assume that an error occurs during `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))`, then it is because Object was used during writing.
Local Storage added Object `data` :  `localStorage.setItem('user', data)` ( fulfilled our order)

`localStorage.getItem(data)` // output : [object Object]
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))` // output  "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

repair:

> `localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(data));`

or:

> `localStorage['user'] = JSON.stringify(data);`